# How to get the url of the route when router deactivate event is fired

Tags: angular

I have implemented router deactivate gaurd in angular2 app which works fine..Is it possible to get the next router state of the application when router deactivate event is fired.I mean the url of the link which user has clicked.Because I want to postpone the navigation where i need to perform some more logic(like animations and cleaning up of data & more)...In the deprecated routes i had argument next which used to hold the next route url.And it is not there in the current router...Is there any way i can get the url of the next route that will be activated... Can somebody please help me out